# Get Amazon item images and description from ASIN

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a sort of shopping list web app in which you can link items to their Amazon's equivalent.

But I'm wondering how to do so. Is there any API? If so, is there a javascript API?

I'd like to:

a) Fetch an item image and description using their ASIN

b) Fetch search's results for a certain term.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that by using [node-apac](https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac), a node.js client for Amazon's Product Advertising API. However, to use the Amazon API you have to open a Amazon Web Services (AWS) account.  Follow these steps.

1. Open a AWS account. Note: Amazon will ask you for a credit card on sign-up, but the Product Advertising API is free, so you won't be charged.
2. Login into your AWS account and go to [Security Credentials page](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials?) to find out your Access Key ID and Secret Access Key
3. Enroll into Amazon Associates Program and get your Associate Tag. This will allow you to receive commission from Amazon for the referrals you send to them.
4. Install node-apac

   ```
   npm install apac@latest
   ```
5. Here is a code snippet that accomplishes your task b) for Amazon search query. It comes from the node-apac page, credit goes to dmcquay

   ```
   var util = require('util'),
   OperationHelper = require('apac').OperationHelper;

   var opHelper = new OperationHelper({
       awsId:     '[YOUR ACCESS KEY ID HERE]',
       awsSecret: '[YOUR SECRET ACCESS KEY HERE]',
       assocId:   '[YOUR ASSOCIATE TAG HERE]', 
   });

   opHelper.execute('ItemSearch', {
       'SearchIndex': 'Books',
       'Keywords': 'harry potter',
       'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes,Offers'
   }, function(error, results) {
       if (error) { console.log('Error: ' + error + "\n"); }
       console.log("Results:\n" + util.inspect(results) + "\n");
   });
   ```

For the task a) of fetching an item image and description you do this:

```
opHelper.execute('ItemLookup', {
    'ItemId': '[ASIN GOES HERE]',
    'MechantId': 'All',
    'Condition': 'All',
    'ResponseGroup': 'Medium'
}, function(error, results) {
    if (error) { console.log('Error: ' + error + "\n"); }
    console.log("Results:\n" + util.inspect(results) + "\n");
});
```

That's it. Check the "results" object for the fields you need. It should include product images, description, and a lot more.

Comment: Wow! This is an incredibly complete answer! Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Comment: Thanks for this, but I can't find any docs or example on what I want to do with the API. I just don't know what to look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Arik G's comment on the node-apac api, you can use the full Node.js library for AWS to get access to product search, etc. http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/4272.

As Judge Mental mentions, the affiliate main page had a list of resource which have documentation and a developer guide.  I find using the [ScratchPad](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html) very useful for testing that I have the correct Account keys or making sample queries.